# Why is Serilog.Sinks.Loggly deprecated

Tags: serilog, loggly

I am using loggly to organize my logs. I am using serilog on my dotnet applications.
These are my questions

- why is the sink for loggly deprecated?
- Should I move to another log management service?
- Is there any alternative to this sink or should I create my own?

My concern is that the package will be removed from nuget one day and I am not yet ready for it.

Thanks.

Comment: look at [this](https://github.com/serilog-archive/serilog-sinks-loggly/issues/58) to know why it was deprecated. as an alternative you could use `seq`.

Comment: Thanks @CodingMytra I will take a look at it. Looks good. I am also looking at Kibana, as I worked with it before.